# Suppress output of object when plotting in IPython

Tags: pandas, ipython

Is it possible to suppress the array output when plotting a histogram in IPython?

For example:

```
plt.hist(OIR['Range'], bins, named=True, histtype='bar')
```

outputs/prints the array information before displaying the graph.

[image: IPython histogram]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Assign the return value to a variable (which I call `_` to indicate it's unused):

```
_ = plt.hist(...)
```

Comment: alternately, you can suppress output by putting a semicolon at the end of the last line: `plot(foo);`

Answer (score 60):

Just put `;` after the code.

It works only in [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter).

`plt.hist(...);`

Comment: Brilliant solution! The reason this works is because the notebook shows the return value of the last command. By adding `;` the last command is "nothing" so there is no return value to show.

Answer (score 5):

You can also add `plt.show()`:

```
plt.hist(OIR['Range'], bins, named=True, histtype='bar')
plt.show()
```

Comment: How does that suppress the output (*"prints the array information before displaying the graph"*)? How does it work? It seems like a ***bogus answer***. Is it?

Comment: The OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*. Perhaps somebody else can chime in?