# Matplotlib figure drawn twice

Tags: python, matplotlib

The function in the code snippet below should create a simple `matplotlib` figure and return it.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def random_figure():
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, squeeze=True)
    for ax in axes:
        ax.plot(*np.random.rand(10, 2))
    return fig
```

What I don't understand is that the figure it is drawn more often than expected:

- If I store the return value with `my_fig = random_figure()`, it is still drawn.
- If I just run `random_figure()`, it is shown twice:

[image]

Is this a setting in matplotlib I'm unaware of?

I'm using jupyter notebook in vscode, if that's relevant.

---

PS, my expectation is that it behave like the function

```
def random_number():
    return np.random.rand()
```

which outputs nothing when the return value is stored with `my_num = random_number()`.

Comment: Is there any additional configuration in your jupyter notebbok, like `%matplotlib inline`?

Comment: No, I only run the above code

Comment: vscode's `settings.json` has a few jupyter-settings, but nothing that seems related

Comment: Ok I tried a bit more and `%matplotlib inline` has no effect, but `%matplotlib widget` indeed returns the expected number of plots. So I guess that's it. Still confused as to why the initial behaviour would make sense

Answer (score 2):

You are observing it printing twice because of the REPL-like design of the final referenced item of each Jupyter cell, see first two sentences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72722172/8508004). In Jupyter this limits it to showing it once:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def random_figure():
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, squeeze=True)
    for ax in axes:
        ax.plot(*np.random.rand(10, 2))
    return fig
random_figure();
```

Remember the end of a cell is special because of the REPL design for it. That is why you can just put a variable on the final line of a cell and get the value back without needing `print(my_variable)`.
The code block above works because the last things the cell sees is `;` which returns nothing.
With what you had, it returns the plot and so it shows it yet again after it's made it.

With `my_fig = random_figure()` you don't see it twice because what is returned by `random_figure()` gets consumed by the assignment.

The trick with adding the `;` is often used to suppress object codes of plots (things that like `<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>'`) and sometimes more from showing up in addition to your plot in the output area, see [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31792131/8508004), in particular  Kynan's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31792131/8508004) explaining why it works.